# Working on a Quadcopter. Unsure if this flight controller supports an FS-IA6 receiver

Tags: quadcopters, betaflight, flight-controller, receiver

I am really new to drone building and I have had some awful luck trying to figure out what is compatible with what. Here is the link to the AIO flight controller I chose to use for my build. It won't be a tiny build but I will still use this flight controller --> [The Flight Controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08N4GCQX3)

I am also using this Fly Sky Remote and Receiver --> [The Remote and Receiver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CWBQ2HM)

My main concern is using the FS-IA6 receiver with the SPI RX setup on the flight controller. Does anyone have advice on such a configuration? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Theoretically, I believe that iBus should work on any UART RX pad, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Actually, nevermind! The FS-iA6 doesn't support iBus.

Comment: @ifconfig what should I do then? Can I not use the FS-iA6 with this flight controller? If so, which Remote and Receiver should I get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I don't believe the components you have are entirely compatible with one another. The FS-iA6 RX only has PWM/PPM outputs, while the BetaFPV F4 AIO 1-2S FC requires some kind of serial RX. The "SPI RX" module mentioned in the spec sheet appears to just be a small FrSky RC module that BetaFPV sells and not something that would allow you to connect to your RX.

I think your cheapest mode of recovery is to get a <$15 USD FS-RX2A receiver, like [this listing on Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/FS-RX2A-Receiver-Evolution-Transmitter-80-150mm/dp/B07KXGHPR6). This model is featured on your FC's Amazon listing, including a wiring diagram:

[image]

It has a serial port output (*Flysky iBus*), which should be entirely compatible with the FC and Betaflight.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I love the advice. Do you think that I could also return the remote and the receiver (as I had recently purchased it) and just get the receiver that supports the SPI RX pins on the flight controller? Then, I would also separately purchase a remote that supports this? That way, I actually might save some money and ultimately, be able to control the drone.

Comment: Technically, yes you could! The ***sold separately*** SPI RX (https://betafpv.com/products/spi-frsky-receiver) supports the "D8" FrSky protocol, so you'd need a compatible radio if you wanted to use that. There are many of them, including ones not sold/produced by FrSky, so there isn't one clear recommendation I can make in that regard.

Comment: Although, I urge caution if you choose to get a TX made by FrSky. They've pulled some serious shenanigans recently with some of their radios by making versions that don't support some older protocols like D8. I don't have FrSky gear to confirm for myself, but I have it on good authority that you should stay away from "ACCESS"-branded ones for "D8" RXs. (https://www.reddit.com/r/fpv/comments/gl3jhg/can_i_get_d8_mode_on_my_taranis_qx7_acess)

Comment: Unfortunately, though, you'll almost certainly be spending a lot more money to do this. The FlySky gear is ~\$50 USD, while a comparable FrSky D8 setup will likely cost you ~\$200 USD.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! This was very helpful.

Comment: Agree with what @ifconfig has commented. A ~\$15 FS-Rx2A is the cheapest way to get stuff to work. Although I think that if you plan on getting a different radio, consider getting some OpenTx radio instead of FrSky. There are budget options which you can get for as less as ~\$50-70 + Around ~\$10-20 for a receiver. Don't think that's ideal if you don't plan to fly a lot though and are on a budget. FS-i6 would serve you well in that case.